# Can't change (reset) Email verify status to false after clicking verify link

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I have created simple chat Application using Android and Firebase. I am using firebase authentication for the user login (email and password as the login credentials) and registration. I works fine. Now "isVerified" status is true. After log in to the application user can change the email address (which is given when the login) to a new email. After changing that email I need to change the "isVerified" status to false to verify newly entered email. So How can I change the "isVerified" status of particular user?

Comment: Hmmm.... I'd expect the verified status to automatically change after you call `updateEmail`. Does that not happen?

Comment: Nope.... Once we verified the email address it automatically changes the verified status to "True". But we cannot change it to "False" manually or automatically (which means not verified) after verifying the email address

Comment: As said, I'd expect the account to become unverified automatically when you change the email address. If that doesn't happen, it might be worth [reaching out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting. Either way, you can't change the status client-side as that would be a security risk. But the Admin SDKs have an option to change the verification status, as shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user